# Github workflows: repsoitory not found in action/checkout section

Tags: github-actions, pypi

I'm trying to get my python project to update on Pypi automatically through a github workflow.
I've never done a github workflow (or any workflow). It doesn't seem to work.

It's this line: `uses: action/checkout@main` under the `build-n-publish` part.

It always fails and I get: Unable to resolve action `action/checkout@main`, repository not found.
and this happens no matter what I put in place of main whether it's v1, v2, master, etc...

I couldn't find anything online explaining it. What should I have in place of main?

for context the `.yml` file:

```
name: CI
on: 
  push:
    branches: 
      - main

jobs:
  build-n-publish:
    name: build and publish pee to pypi
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - uses: action/checkout@pee
        with: 
          repository: ''
      - name: Set up Python 3.6
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: 3.6
      - name: Install pypa/build
        run: >-
          python -m
          pip install
          build
          --user
      - name: Build a binary wheel and a source tarball
        run: >-
          python -m
          build
          --sdist
          --wheel
          --outdir dist/
      - name: Publish distribution  to Test PyPI
        uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@master
        with:
          password: ${{ secrets.pypi_password }}
          repository_url: https://pypi.org/legacy/
      - name: Publish distribution  to PyPI
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags')
        uses: pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@master
        with:
          password: ${{ secrets.pypi_password }}.
```

Comment: Why do force the `repository: ''`? Just remove the line along with `with:` and leave the `- uses: actions/checkout` step without any parameters. The workflow will detect the `repository` automatically.